# Ormlite objectcache behaviour when using select colums in query builder

Tags: android, ormlite, query-builder

I am using the object cache in OrmLite for my Daos to ensure that for each object there is only one instance in my app.

Now I discovered a problem when I restrict the query to select only a subset of the columns. E.g. when I want all IDs that are currently stored in the database. I used the following code to do that.

```
Dao<Data, String> dao = getDao(Data.class, String.class);
List<Data> dataList = dao.queryBuilder().selectColumns("id").query();
```

I used this solution for performance reasons because it is a lot faster than querying the whole object.

What is happening now is that those Data objects returned by the query are stored in the objectcache too. So when I do a normal query (without selectColumns) for a Data object after it I get the one from the cache with all other entries null.

Is this a bug?

Answer (score 0):

We ran into the same issue today and concluded that it is not safe to use `selectColumns()` in conjunction with object caching.

I'll leave it up to you to decide whether it is a bug, a conceptual issue or a design decision.